# Как грамотно избежать 'no-unused-vars' в JavaScript - вопрос начинающего

Tags: javascript, переменные

Решаю задачу в курсе по основам программирования в JavaScript.

Суть задачи: поиск наименьшего делителя при помощи переменных и цикла `while`.

Код работает, но линтер выдает ошибку 'no-unused-vars' для переменно `let iterLet`.

Документацию по замечанию линтера — no-unused-vars (https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars) прочёл, но знаний пока не хватает самостоятельно устранить ошибку.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как грамотно обернуть в функцию "проблемную" переменную?

Я знаю, что конкретно здесь можно обойтись и без этой переменной. Но мне важно понять сам принцип на этом примере, как писать код грамотно, так чтобы не возникало этой ошибки. Вариант с комментарием `// eslint-disable-line no-unused-vars` уже нашел.

Мой код:

```
    const smallestDivisor = (num) => {
      let iterLet = num;
      let div = 2;

      while (num % div) {
        iterLet /= div;
        div += 1;

      }
      return div;
    };
```

Comment: Зачем вам здесь переменная `iterLet`? Что изменится если строки `let iterLet = num;` `iterLet /= div;` просто удалить?

Comment: удалить переменные которые не используються, и больше так не делать  )

Comment: @AntonShchyrov, здесь, эта переменная используется, как промежуточное значение. Вы правы, если её удалить, код работает и так. Я сначала выполнил задание так, как понял (тот код, который в вопросе). А потом увидел учительский вариант без этих строк. Но мне хочется разобраться, как можно написать так, чтобы и мои строки сохранились и так, чтобы ошибок не было. Это просто нужно мне для понимания. Преподы отправили меня в документацию, я ее прочел, но пока не понял.

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych, спасибо. Походу я себе решил просто усложнить жизнь)

Comment: @Evgeny похоже )))

Comment: @Evgeny "эта переменная используется, как промежуточное значение" - не используется. Обратите внимание, что Ваш код только присваивает значение этой переменной, но нигде не использует ее значение ни для вычисления других значений, ни в логике.

Comment: @Igor спасибо, теперь уже сам не знаю, зачем я ввёл эту переменную. Два дня потратил, чтобы "обойти" её, и теперь выяснилось, что она там не нужна. Тысяча фейспалмов...

Comment: вообще она нужна, и в твоем коде в она должна была быть тут `while (num % div) {` вместо `num`, потому что в текущем виде у тебя бесконечный цикл, если `num` не делится нацело на `div`